# How to get LinkedIn Company status update comments using API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get comments to one particular Company status update using update-key. It is not documented in the manual, but when trying to call the link similar to Network status update  link I can get some data, but the result data is not correct (it's addressed to another post). 
The link is : http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company_id}/updates/key={update-key}/update-comments .

I am just wondering whether it is possible using API and whether this feature is in plans?

Answer (score 0):

Reading Company updates is available in preview mode as of this answer:

https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-updates

However, there does not appear to be any published support for pulling a particular update by it's id. You can specify the type, and paginate through the results, but pulling a particular update does not appear to be supported, per the docs linked above.

Comment: How to get the ids of the company ? Is there any api which LinkedIn provides such as for facebook we have /accounts and get all the pages with that account ?

Comment: You can use the [Company Search API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search) to lookup the ids, or the [Company Profile plugin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile-plugin) to manually lookup the ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible, however the LinkedIn API documentation seems to have some typos in the examples:

```
v1/companies/{company_id}/updates/key={update_key}
```

I was able to get this to work!